# How to to download MP3 file from AGI script written in Perl?

Tags: perl, asterisk, telephony, agi

I am trying to download an MP3 file from an [AGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_Gateway_Interface) script written in Perl, however the file does not get downloaded. The strange thing is that if I try to download the same file from a plain Perl script it gets downloaded.

Here's my AGI code:

```
use Asterisk::AGI;

$AGI = new Asterisk::AGI;

my %input = $AGI->ReadParse();

$AGI->answer();

sub getAudioFile
{
    $filename = shift;

    open(FH, ">./audio.mp3") || die "error";

    binmode(FH);

    $AGI->verbose("Downloading audio file");

    $http_query = "curl http://www.something.com/cgi-bin/downloadfile.cgi? -d \"type=mp3&filename=$filename\" -s |";

    open (PIPER, $http_query) or die "sorry";

    $rets = "";

    while (<PIPER>)
    {
        $rets .= $_;
    }

    close(PIPER);
    chomp $rets;

    print FH $rets;
    close(FH);

    $AGI->verbose("Download complete");


}

getAudioFile('somefile.mp3');

$AGI->hangup();
```

What could be going wrong here ?

Comment: What happens? Does it die with "sorry"? Does it connect to the http server? Are you sure $filename is set to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This line fails:

```
$AGI->answer();
```

Check the return value in the code.

From [Asterisk::AGI - Simple Asterisk Gateway Interface Class](http://search.cpan.org/~jamesgol/asterisk-perl-0.09/lib/Asterisk/AGI.pm):

> $AGI->answer()
>
> Executes AGI Command "ANSWER"
>
> Answers channel if not already in
>   answer state
>
> Example: $AGI->answer();
>
> Returns: -1 on channel failure, or 0
>   if successful

Answer (score 0):

Try running the "getAudioFile" portion of the perl script as the 'Asterisk' user (whatever is running asterisk). This will more closely emulate what is happening when Asterisk spawns the API.

Maybe it's a user-permissions error.